# How to prove that no hamiltonian cycle exists in the graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonicity

** Show that the graph below has a hamiltonian path but no hamiltonian cycle.
[image]

You can find more than one hamiltonian path such as $(b,a,c,f,e,g,d)$.
Actually, I tried many times to find a hamiltonian cycle, but I couldn't find a cycle. The problem is how to prove that no hamiltonian cycle exists. I need a logical proof. I can't say "I tried many times but I couldn't find a hamiltonian cycle" because it's not reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if you delete the edge joining $g$ and $f$, then you get the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,4}$ with sides $\{g,a,f\}$ and $\{b,d,c,e\}$.

It may help now to redraw the graph in the usual way $K_{3,4}$ is drawn. In any case, now you need prove that there is no Hamilton cycle in $K_{3,4}$ *and* no Hamilton path from $g$ to $f$. Use the fact that the two sides have different number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the $3$-subset $\{a,f,g\}$ yields $4$ connected components.  Because $3<4$, this subset yields a certificate that the graph does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle.